# Crystal Reports: Must print empty page on odd page numbers

Tags: printing, crystal-reports

I'm using crystal reports 10 and have an issue with a duplex printer.

Basically I've a report  that used to print to a printer in non-duplex mode. This report prints a list of new users created on a particular day. Previously this report would print 1 user per sheet.

We've had a change of printer which only prints duplex and now a new user is printed on the front and back of a sheet.

Is there a way to tell it to print an empty page after each user? This must be easy but CR is not my area of expertise.

Regards,

Sapatos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your existing report is printing 1 user per sheet, I would assume this is because it is grouped by user and either the New Page Before option is checked for the group header section, or the New Page After option is checked for the group footer.

If so, and if the group footer section is suppressed, then alternate pages can be skipped by unsuppressing the (blank) group footer section and checking the New Page Before option for that section. (If the group footer section is already visible and contains data, create a new, blank footer sub-section at the end of the group footer section and adjust the new page options accordingly.)

If not, please can you supply further details as to how your report is organised?

Comment: actually fixed this at the printer rather than the report but thanks for the answer